# Fill a data.frame with loop, levels sets are different

Tags: r

I am new in R and this issue might be very elementary.
I am using R to fit a gamma distribution to some data, these data are in the "modelset" dataset.

I want to create a new data frame in which I can list the coefficients of the gamma distribution for certain observations using a loop.

This is what I have done:

I created a vector with the observations for which I need the coefficient.

```
Format<- c('10x2', '10x3','10x7', '17x15', '17x7', '20x2', '20x3','25x4','4 column','5 column','7x7','DPS','FP')
```

Then I created another object which I need to fill with the loop (Shape = Shape of the gamma distribution).

```
Shape<- 1:13
```

Then I created the data.frame with the two objects

```
GammaShape<- data.frame(Format, Shape)
```

Finally I wanted to use a loop to fill the column "Shape" with the values.

```
for (i in GammaShape$Shape) { GammaShape$Shape[i] = coef(fitdistr(modelset$ETTime[which(modelset$Format == GammaShape$Format[i])]/1000))}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in Ops.factor(modelset$Format, GammaShape$Format[i]) : level sets of factors are different
```

Despite the fact that levels are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my recommendation would be twofold. First, just don't use factors when creating the data.frame; you can factor post-hoc if you really need them. So:

```
GammaShape <- data.frame(Format, Shape, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Second: for loops are a really inefficient way to modify data.frames, because of how data.frames are stored and modified: every time you tweak a value, you're actually recreating the data.frame in its (new) format and assigning it to the old name, which is computationally expensive with big objects. While this is a very small data.frame, I'd suggest getting into the habit of operating on individual vectors wherever possible, and merging into a data.frame *after* you've finished iterating. So:

```
Format <- c('10x2', '10x3', '10x7', '17x15', '17x7', '20x2', '20x3',
            '25x4', '4 column', '5 column', '7x7', 'DPS', 'FP')

Shape <- numeric(length(Format))

for(i in seq_along(Shape)){
     Shape[i] <- coef(fitdistr(modelset$ETTime[which(modelset$Format == Format[i])]/1000))
}

GammaShape <- data.frame(Format, Shape, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

...and then if you want to factor, well, apply `as.factor`. Note that this solution works *to the best of my knowledge* - your example doesn't show us modelset.

Comment: Thank you!, that partly solved some issues. But now it is filling only the first row for Shape and it is returning me that in fitdistr, x must be a non-empty numeric vector..

Comment: I assume you mean that it's filling the first one and then throwing an error, not that it's repeatedly writing to the first one while throwing warnings? And, well, look at the object you're passing in for x when i is 2. Is it a non-empty vector? Without you making the datasets available it's pretty difficult to diagnose specifically.

Comment: No it fills the first one and then it fills the rest with 0.0000

Comment: Plus, I have a warning message. In Shape[i] <- coef(fitdistr(modelset$ETTime[which(modelset$Format ==:number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. But it might be that the problem is with the data in modelset. Thanks though!